# custom wordpress plugin not doing anything

Tags: php, api, wordpress

I want to write a simple plugin that calls API of a website I use and gives back list of links/urls back to me.

I am trying to follow the gazillion "write your own simple wordpress plugin" links but not getting it right.

This is what I've done:
1) created a plugin file under plugins/myplugin.php which looks something like this:

```
function myplugin()
{
   // making api call via curl
   // return the result
   return $result;
}
```

I've activated this plugin in wordpress admin panel.

I want to call this on a specific page of my website. That page is written in php.

I am doing simple `<?php $blah=myplugin(); echo "$blah"; ?>`

But its not doing anything. What am I missing.

**Edit:0**

When I do "view selection source" on the page where I am trying to use this function, I get:

```
<div class="post">
<!--?php $blah=myfunction(); echo "$blah"; ?-->
</div>
```

Does that seem correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that $result contains any information at all?
If you use echo statements inside of myplugin() that will print on your site.
Because from what I can see you're not doing anything wrong.

Also, obviously, make sure that you call your plugin from the current template.

Comment: I am getting results. BTW, how do I make sure I am calling for "current template"?

Comment: Well thats easy, in the backend you have a button named Appearence>Themes if you click on that on you will see which of the installed themes is the currently used one, in the default install of the latest wordpress that would be Twenty Eleven so just make sure that you write your code in one of the files in the wp-content/themes/twentyeleven folder.

Comment: okay, so under wp-content/ I have plugins/ (where I have my plugin) and then I have themes/ where I have my theme. But I want to use myfunction() inside a page that I am adding. I am not getting what you are suggesting.

Comment: well wordpress themes run from the index.php in for example the folder twentyeleven try adding your code somewhere in that file, i suggest that you do it in the end of the file. For the rest of it, that's a far to long answer for me to give here so i suggest you check this out this site: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development

Comment: This is the part I am not getting. How to use the myfunction() function I created in the plugin. I do not want it to appear on all the pages. I want to use it only on 1 page. All the pages use "page" template.

Comment: If thats the case then you'll have to work with conditionals, because a page in wordpress is just a type of page, there are posts and pages. Play around a little in the backend and you'll figure it out.